# Can default ASP.Net WebApi parameter binding work for query parameters containing dash("-")?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I'm refering to parameter binding here:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

But the query parameter that I want to bind is 'api-version' which isn't a legal C# identifier. What is the simplest way to make this bind to a C# property called 'ApiVersion' [just as if the query parameter were actually 'apiVersion=']?

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON.NET JsonProperty](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute magic,

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName="api-version")]
public int ApiVersion { get; set; }
```

Comment: It would probaly work with a json payload body but isn't working for me if it is a query parameter in the URI "?api-version="

Comment: `-` is indeed unreserved according to the RFC spec. hmmm

Answer (score 0):

The `FromUri` attribute has an optional `Name` property.

```
public IHttpActionResult Version([FromUri(Name="api-version")] string apiVersion)
{
    ...
}
```